# Getting "unexpected error" message when trying to create table on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I get an "unexpected error" message every time I try to create a table on BigQuery. I've tried inputting and omitting the schema and made sure that the file was compatible with csv format.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.

I did a couple of things to clean up the csv file and I was then able to upload it successfully

- Remove commas from any numerical data
- If using auto detect for schema remove any spaces between headings
- Remove header data completely and define schema

Comment: Update: cleaning up the headers (taking out commas, parentheses etc) worked for me. Bigquery was able to ID the schema and I’m good to go. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I HAD THE SAME PROBLEM AND I WRITE DATA TYPES IN CAPITAL.
and my problem of "unexpected error was gone"
FOR EX- TYPE (STRING) NOT (string)
TYPE (INTEGER) NOT (integer) same on.......